# Formal parameter "Item" is not referenced

Tags: ada

**By using subprograms, I try to write a program that displays a VAT table. It asks the user to enter some data and based on these data, displays a VAT-table. However, I get a warning which says: "Formal parameter "Item" is not referenced". My program does display a table but it looks terrible. Here you can see how far I have come:**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Underprogram is
V_percent, S_length, H_price, L_price, Price_Wm : Float;
 X: Integer;

procedure Get_Pop(Item : out Float ) is
begin
  Put_Line("Write ur first price:");
Get(H_price, width=>0);
while H_price < 0.0 loop
  Put("Wrong inout, try again! : ");
  Get(H_price);
end loop;

loop
Put_Line("Write in your second price:");
  Get(L_price, width=>0);
  if H_price > L_price then
  exit; end if; end loop;

Put_Line("Which VAT percent do ypu want? ");
Get(V_percent, width=>0);
while V_percent > 100.0 or V_percent <= 0.0 loop
  Put_Line("The vat percent you fed in is invalid, try again! ");
  Get(V_percent);
  end loop;

Put_Line("Which step length do you want? ");
Get(S_length, width=>0);
while S_length < 0.1 or S_length > 1.0 loop
  Put_Line("The step length you just fed in is out of the range: ");
  Get(S_length);
end loop;  end Get_Pop;

procedure Put_pop(Item : in Float) is
  
  begin
  X := Integer(Float'Floor((H_price-L_price) / S_length + 1.0));
Put_Line("              === Vattabell ===               ");
Put_Line("Price without VAT    Vat      Price with VAT ");
Put_Line("---------------     ----      -------------- ");
for I in 0..X -1  loop

 Price_Wm := L_price + Float(I) * S_length;
 Put(Price_Wm, 5,2,0);

 Put((L_price + Float(I) * S_length) * V_percent/100.0,
      13,2,0);

  Put(Price_Wm * (1.0 +  V_percent/100.0), 15,2,0);

  New_Line;
end loop;
  end Put_pop;
begin
Get_Pop(V_percent); Put_pop(V_percent);
Get_Pop(S_length);  Put_pop(S_length);
Get_Pop(H_price); Put_pop(H_price);
Get_Pop(L_price); Put_pop(L_price);
Get_Pop(Price_Wm); Put_pop(Price_Wm);
  end Underprogram;
```

**Here is an update: I just rewrote my code based in the comments and it works fine. Now I wonder how I can add more functions and subprograms to this code so that the Underprogram procedure looks cleaner?. Right now I have just two subprograms:**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;   use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
  
procedure Underprogram is
Higher, Lower, VAT, Step, Price_without_VAT: Float;
X                        : Integer;
procedure Get_data(Item: out Float) is
begin
  Get(Item);
end Get_data;
procedure Put_data(Item: in Float) is
begin
  Put(Item, 2,2,0); Put(" ");
end Put_data;
begin
Put("Write the higher price: ");
Get_data(Higher);
while Higher < 0.0 loop
Put("Wrong input, try again: ");
Get_data(Higher); end loop;
  
loop
Put("Write the lower price: ");
     Get_data(Lower);
     if Lower < Higher then
        exit; end if; end loop;
     
  Put("Write the VAT : ");
  Get_data(VAT);
  while VAT > 100.0 or VAT < 0.0 loop
     Put("Wrong input, try again:");
     Get_data(VAT);
     end loop;
     
     loop
        Put("Write the step: ");
        Get_data(Step);
        if Step > 0.0 then
        exit; end if; end loop;
 Put_data(Higher);
 Put_data(Lower);
 Put_data(VAT);
 Put_data(Step);

 X := Integer(Float'Floor((Higher-Lower) / Step + 1.0));
Put_Line("              === VATTABELL ===               ");
Put_Line("Price without VAT      VAT      Price with VAT ");
Put_Line("---------------     ----      -------------- ");
for I in 0..X -1  loop

  Price_without_VAT := Higher + Float(I) * Step;
  Put(Price_without_VAT, 5,2,0);
  Put((Higher + Float(I) * Step) * VAT/100.0, 13,2,0);
  Put(Price_without_VAT * (1.0 +  VAT/100.0), 15,2,0);
  New_Line;
end loop;
end Underprogram;
```

Comment: You might point out that the warning also tells you that the problem is on line 9. And at line 9 there is a subprogram, with a formal parameter "Item". Which is. indeed, not referenced.  Did you have a question about that?

Comment: Well, it might be that you intended to use the formal, to pass a result into the actual, but forgot. If you did ...that's a serious bug so fix it. If you didn't ... delete it ... as it's the only parameter, delete the whole parameter list (ditto in all calls to it).

Comment: Your formatting is chaotic. Your code would benefit from use of a pretty printer. A more consistent use of indentation within functions, procedures, and loops will help you understand the errors in your program.

Comment: I misunderstood the question but yes this is the warning I get, however my program displays the table. The table looks terrible so I thought, the problem might be the warning I get. Would be nice if someone could fix this bug

Comment: @JimRogers yes, it looks terrible. I'm a complete beginner and do not know how to make it looks better. I have to work on it a lot

Comment: @Shamim Which Ada compiler do you use? It might come with a pretty printer utility. That utility can help organize your source code.

Comment: The table looks fine to me, just wrong (the 'Vat' column is always zero). Your choice of subprogram names is confusing; I’ve no idea what `Underprogram` means, `Get_Pop` should be called something like `Read_Table_Parameters` (and take no parameters), `Put_Pop` should be `Print_Table` (and take no parameters). `H_Price` is ok-ish, likewise `L_Price`, though why abbreviate? What is `S_Length`? What on earth is `Wm_Price`??? As to the code, why do you ask for "first" and "second" price when you mean high and low? When complaining about invalid VAT, why don’t you say what would be valid? etc ...

Answer (score 1):

The following code is your code after re-organized by the pretty printer provided in the GNAT Studio 2020 Community Edition:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;   use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Underprogram is
   V_percent, S_length, H_price, L_price, Price_Wm : Float;
   X                                               : Integer;

   procedure Get_Pop (Item : out Float) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Write ur first price:");
      Get (H_price, Width => 0);
      while H_price < 0.0 loop
         Put ("Wrong inout, try again! : ");
         Get (H_price);
      end loop;

      loop
         Put_Line ("Write in your second price:");
         Get (L_price, Width => 0);
         if H_price > L_price then
            exit;
         end if;
      end loop;

      Put_Line ("Which VAT percent do ypu want? ");
      Get (V_percent, Width => 0);
      while V_percent > 100.0 or V_percent <= 0.0 loop
         Put_Line ("The vat percent you fed in is invalid, try again! ");
         Get (V_percent);
      end loop;

      Put_Line ("Which step length do you want? ");
      Get (S_length, Width => 0);
      while S_length < 0.1 or S_length > 1.0 loop
         Put_Line ("The step length you just fed in is out of the range: ");
         Get (S_length);
      end loop;
   end Get_Pop;

   procedure Put_pop (Item : in Float) is

   begin
      X := Integer (Float'Floor ((H_price - L_price) / S_length + 1.0));
      Put_Line ("              === Vattabell ===               ");
      Put_Line ("Price without VAT    Vat      Price with VAT ");
      Put_Line ("---------------     ----      -------------- ");
      for I in 0 .. X - 1 loop

         Price_Wm := L_price + Float (I) * S_length;
         Put (Price_Wm, 5, 2, 0);

         Put ((L_price + Float (I) * S_length) * V_percent / 100.0, 13, 2, 0);

         Put (Price_Wm * (1.0 + V_percent / 100.0), 15, 2, 0);

         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end Put_pop;
begin
   Get_Pop (V_percent);
   Put_pop (V_percent);
   Get_Pop (S_length);
   Put_pop (S_length);
   Get_Pop (H_price);
   Put_pop (H_price);
   Get_Pop (L_price);
   Put_pop (L_price);
   Get_Pop (Price_Wm);
   Put_pop (Price_Wm);

end Underprogram;
```

I simply copied the source into the GNAT Studio IDE, saved the file, then chose the Pretty Print option under the Code tab in the IDE. I did nothing to manually format the code.
See how the use of indentation helps visually identify the beginning and ending of procedures, functions, and loops.

Comment: Should not we write "Item" in all the getters? And if we do then how would if statements look like? you can not just write " if  Item > Item  then .......

Comment: Your procedure Get_Pop is not a classical "getter". A getter retrieves a private value from a tagged type. Your program does not employ tagged types. Get_Pop performs I/O and gets values from Standard Input. Since Get_Pop populates values global to Get_Pop the procedure Get_Pop does not need a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the first pass through the table reports the VAT data as zero is that you pass `V_Percent` to `Get_Pop` as the actual for the `out` parameter `Item`, but *you* never assign to `Item`, with the result that the compiler assigns *something* to it on exit from the procedure, overwriting the value of `V_Percent` which you already assigned explicitly.

`Get_Pop` can’t logically have a single `out` parameter, because its job (as you’ve coded it) is to read **four** values. Either no parameters at all, or give each required value its own `out` parameter, or create a record type to hold all 4 values.